# How to find the strings of a string list that start with a given prefix?

Tags: haskell

I want to write a helper function that could return a string list

```
helper ['Excuse','Me', 'Exit', 'And'] 'Ex'
```

and this should return

```
['Excuse','Exit']
```

I search up and find in `Data.List` have the `isInfixOf` function could compare two string, but how could I recursive call to find the correct String list

```
helper :: [String] -> String -> [String]
helper [] _ = []  
helper (x:xs) std 
    | isInfixOf x std == True : helper
```

Comment: The syntax for guards is `| condition = value`, you don't have the equals sign. Try ` | isInfixOf x std = x : helper xs std`

Comment: You could use the `filter` function instead of using a recursive definition.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost entirely there.

To call `helper` on a list `["Excuse", "Me", "Exit", "And"]` named, oh let's say `myList`, you'd write:

```
helper myList "Ex"
```

Now, when you pattern match that list with `x:xs`, `xs` is the tail of the list, which is just another list. To call `helper` recursively on this, you'd just write `helper xs std`.

You do not need to explicitly compare the return of `isInfixOf` to `True`. You also need to handle the case where `isInfixOf x std` is *not* true.

```
helper :: [String] -> String -> [String]
helper [] _ = []  
helper (x:xs) std 
    | isInfixOf x std = x : helper xs std
    | otherwise = helper xs std
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a reason to do that with a recursive function. You want to keep elements of a list that fulfill a certain predicate (`"Ex"` being an infix of the element). The [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) function does exactly that.

```hs
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

helper :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
helper = flip (filter . isInfixOf)
```

For example:

```hs
helper ["Excuse", "Me", "Exit", "And"] "Ex"
-- ["Excuse","Exit"]
```